# Python Error when reading data from .xls file

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-excel

I need to read a few xls files into Python.The sample data file can be found through Link:[data.file](http://wp.yhfund.com.cn/os/share.html?pc=id008q). I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('data.xls',sheet=1)
```

But it gives an error message:

> ERROR *** codepage 21010 -> encoding 'unknown_codepage_21010' ->
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: unknown_codepage_21010 Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       pd.read_excel('data.xls',sheet=1)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 113,
>   in read_excel
>       return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 150,
>   in **init**
>       self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 435, in
>   open_workbook
>       ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 116, in
>   open_workbook_xls
>       bk.parse_globals()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1170, in
>   parse_globals
>       self.handle_codepage(data)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 794, in
>   handle_codepage
>       self.derive_encoding()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 775, in
>   derive_encoding
>       _unused = unicode(b'trial', self.encoding)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py", line 30,
>   in 
>       unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
>
> LookupError: unknown encoding: unknown_codepage_21010

Anyone could help with this problem?

PS: I know if I open the file in windows excel, and resave it, the code could work, but I am looking for a solution without manual adjustment.

Comment: Its not only pandasc issue. others have same [problem](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/396)

Answer (score 2):

using the ExcelFile class, I was successfully able to read the file into python.
let me know if this helps!

```
    import xlrd
    import pandas as pd

    xls = pd.ExcelFile(’C:\data.xls’)
    xls.parse(’Index Constituents Data’, index_col=None, na_values=[’NA’])
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't used xlrd in the code here however you imported it.

Answer (score 2):

The below worked for me.

```
import xlrd


my_xls = xlrd.open_workbook('//myshareddrive/something/test.xls',encoding_override="gb2312")
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert my_xls into DataFrame?